# What happens if some hadoop map-reduce Job or some hdfs command is running and in the between kerberos ticket expires?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, apache-pig, kerberos

Lets say we have kerberos secured Hadoop Cluster. ( For example Kdc is configured to provide kerberos tickets with validity of 2 hour and renewal period of 3 hours after this so total 5 hours. )
Cluster also includes tools like Hive and Pig.

With respect to given scenario can any one help me understand the behaviors in each cases mentioned below(Note: Job: Map-Reduce Job, Job Submitted Through Hive Or Pig)

1. Lets say job takes 4 hours to run, I am triggering the job, for next two hours user who triggered the job has valid ticket, job runs fine after two hours Job is out of valid kerberos ticket but it has renewal period left, Will job renew it? Will it stop execution? Is there any property to enable or disable such automatically renewal behavior.
2. Lets say job takes 10 hours to run, I am trigerring the job, for next two hours user who triggered the job has valid ticket, lets say this time after two hours we don't have renewal period left, Will Job continue? Will Job fail with authentication error. Will Job request for new ticket?
3. Let say Job takes 10 hours to run And Kdc is configured to provide 2 hours ticket. we setup a cron job which runs at every 6 hours and gets a new ticket(Technically User will not run out of valid kerberos ticket any time), Will new generated ticket cause any problem of the running job through old ticket?

I want to understand working behavior of this Jobs as well as tools like kerberos, hive and pig.

Comment: Perhaps this  would be of interest? https://blog.cloudera.com/hadoop-delegation-tokens-explained/

Comment: Yeah @mazaneicha Now I understood the delegation mechanism with respect to single map-reduce task. I want to understand more about what happens in case of Hive or Pig job which internally submits more then one map reduce jobs, Lets say one hive or pig Job launches 5 mapreduce job internally from that during start time of two jobs user had valid ticket job launched and ran successfully but after that? I want to know is there any way to achieve this.
Thanks for help, This help is also appreciated.

Comment: Hive will fail a query if one of its MR jobs fails. Pig -- I don't know (ancient technology :)), but I assume it'll depend on how Pig application is written.

Comment: Thanks @mazaneicha is there any way to delegate this or to configure kerberos principle and keytab so whenever any execution of this happens hadoop or hive automatically aquires kerberos tickets. 
After Some research i came across [link](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/HKerberos.html) i tested it, apparently it doesn't want user to initially get kerberos ticket and then trigger job. Pig will automatically takes care of it. It will acquire kerberos ticket if it doesn't have any and renew it also. I am finding similar functionality in hive.

Comment: @mazaneicha I also came accross [this](https://www.opencore.com/blog/2016/5/user-name-handling-in-hadoop/), I noticed that when ever i execute hive in debug mode it dumps parameters of class UserGroupInformation as mentioned in article. How ever it shows null like `23/01/23 23:33:28 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: using kerberos user:null
23/01/23 23:33:28 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: using local user:UnixPrincipal: root` also i want to know how to set this class parameter similarly done in HKerberos, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure. I'd look at other less intrusive options, [k5start](https://linux.die.net/man/1/k5start) for example. BTW, looks like there were some advancemenst in core Hadoop as well https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9567, but I've not dealt with it personally.

Comment: Thanks @mazaneicha k5start looks good, thanks for suggestion i was not aware about any such tool however from stack overflow only I came across one options to put cron job to renew our ticket. This tools do same I guess if no what is the diff? And will not it create problem if I start some job with some ticket A and in the middle I got new ticket, ticket B, specially for hive or pig.

Comment: People who aren't aware of k5start write cron jobs. This discussion is getting too long...